# How to send email from outlook from windows store app?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to send email from my app is it possible to use outlook to send email from windows 8 app???

any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch outlook with this.

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=hello@world.com&subject=Hello%20World&body=this%20is%20body"); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

Comment: No you can't attach file.